# Is there a way to allow characters to see in the underdark like daylight?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light

The question is pretty self explanatory,  I'd like to create an item or boon where a character could see in the Underdark like it was the overworld.

Comment: Can you explain which parts of "Creating a Magic Item" or "Epic Boons" (DMG pp.284 or 230-232, respectively) you had trouble with?

Comment: Do you mean to say you want full color, "unlimited" range viewing, as if you were midday above ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An item or boon could duplicate the Warlock's Invocation of the following:

> **Devil’s Sight** You can *see normally in darkness*, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

This allows a Warlock to see without restriction of the B&W that Darkvision enforces. It is a bit more fleshed out than the entries of the Devils in the MM as they simply state the following:

> **Devil's Sight.** Magical darkness doesn't impede the devil's darkvision.

I am unsure if this is intentional though.

Short of that not even True Seeing technically allows you to see in the dark. Although, since it exists in the game it should be reasonable that someone, depending on the magical frequency of your world may have duplicated the effect in a magical item. I would say that they would be rare at least as the Darkvision of 5E has its disadvantages now, which is good as it used to be the end all be all of why you chose a race/spell if you min/maxed to go delving in the dark.

Comment: I think the Warlock _Devil's Sight_ more thoroughly defines its effects because the _Devil's Sight_ of an actual Devil is also referring to its *Darkvision*, which is described in its Senses.

Comment: What disadvantages does darkvision have? There's nothing I've seen that is a disadvantage, and you're never worse off than a person without it.

Comment: In areas of darkness you treat it as dim light which means you have disadvantage on perception having to do with sight, it is under the lighting section.